# Swift 5.7 - `if let` works on non-optionals inside closures

Tags: swift, swiftui

As far as I know, you can't use `if let` on variables that aren't optional...

```
func run() {
    let title = "Hello, world!"
    if let title = title { /// Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'
        print(title)
    }
}
```

... but for some reason, when it's inside a closure, it works:

```
func run() {
    let title = "Hello, world!"
    let closure = {
        if let title = title { /// No error!
            print(title)
        }
    }
    closure()
}
```

This was on Xcode 14.0 beta (14A5228q). Is this a bug, or a feature? When I tested on Xcode 13.3 (13E113), the error appeared again.

---

On a side note, the following SwiftUI code compiles fine on both Xcode 13 and Xcode 14:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let title = "Hello, world!"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let title = title { /// Works fine!
                Text(title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's not just `VStack` — anything marked [`@ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) seems to work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let title = "Hello, world!"

    var body: some View {
        ContainerView {
            if let title = title { /// works fine!
                Text(title)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContainerView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
}
```

[image: "Hello, world!" displayed]

Is this a documented feature, or a bug?

Comment: As a simple hypothesis, I would say that one inside a closure a variable may become optional as the caller may have disappeared before closure ends. That could explain what you saw. I surely am wrong.

Comment: It looks like an error. The compiler should complain if the variable is not optional and you try to unwrap it. I think a feedback to Apple is in order

Comment: @PtitXav Definitely not, the variable is captured and the compilers makes sure its lifetime survives its usage.

Comment: Good candidate for a Feedback to Apple

Comment: Note that the Swift bugbase has moved (you probably know that already): https://github.com/apple/swift/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Comment: This appears to have been fixed in Swift 5.8, although I can't find the link to the specific issue

Comment: @aheze You might want to give that as an answer, to close out the question. Thanks for keeping track of this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue (which had to do with result builders) is fixed in Swift 5.8. According to an Apple engineer on [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/63808#issuecomment-1439001660):

> This was a bug in 5.7 that previously compiled and impacted compile time performance. I have outlined this issue in the forums post - https://forums.swift.org/t/improved-result-builder-implementation-in-swift-5-8/63192 "Structural Diagnostics" sub-section.