# Why does unwrapping non-optional variable in `some View` compile?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my `ContentView`, I have a non-optional variable, and when I attempt to unwrap it using `if let` inside the body property's `some View` closure, it compiles without any problems. I'm curious about why this occurs and if there is any rationale behind this behavior.

As expected, attempting the same unwrapping in other locations, such as the `init()` method, results in a compile-time error.

Here's a minimal reproducible example for reference:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var nonOptionalVar: Int = 42

    init() {
//        if let unwrappedVar = nonOptionalVar {
//            print("compile error!")
//        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let unwrappedVar = nonOptionalVar {
                Text("This does compile with \(unwrappedVar)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not compile for me, on MacOS 13.3, Xcode 14.3 beta, targeting ios 16.3 and macCatalyst. I get this error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'`. It could be different on older systems. What system are you on?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I'm on Xcode 14.2 and Swift 5.7.2 and was able to reproduce, so it seems like a bug that was fixed?

Comment: yes, most likely. Fixed in Swift 5.8 or SwiftUI.

Comment: I was testing on Xcode 14.2 too. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This was indeed a bug that was fixed in Swift 5.8. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820040/swift-5-7-if-let-works-on-non-optionals-inside-closures